# How to check if a value is NOT in an array using jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm having some trouble with checking if a value is **not** in an array. I'm trying to allow only certain key presses in a textbox.

Here's what I have:

```
var keyCodeArr = [ 8,9,13,17,18,37,39,46 ];
$('#txtSearch').keydown(function(event) {
var code = event.keyCode;

if (!$.inArray(code,keyCodeArr)) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
});
```

It's allowing anything in the textbox. I looked at the documentation for $.inArray(), which show an example for seeing if a value **is** in an array, so I thought just adding the NOT in front of it would do the trick.

Or is it that I'm not initializing the array correctly in the first place?

What am I missing?

Comment: The [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) says to check for -1 values, and `event.which` is normalized in jQuery.

Comment: `I looked at the documentation for $.inArray()` and I see _if we're checking for the presence of value within array, we need to check if it's not equal to (or greater than) -1._

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using jquery:

```
if (!~$.inArray(code,keyCodeArr)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, roasted for the code and adeneo and Peter for pointing out to me that I didn't read the docs close enough!