# jQuery check if value not in array

Tags: jquery, arrays

Tried to get this to work:

```
var instance_name = $('#instance_name').val();
$("#instance_name").on("blur", function(e){
    if (!~$.inArray(instance_name, not_allowed)) {
        $("#instance_alert").html("<font color=green>Instance does not exists. Please continue</font>");
    } else {
        $("#instance_alert").html("<font color=red>Instance exists. Please try another one.</font>");
    }
```

But to no avail.. (Looked into [How to check if a value is NOT in an array using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444586/how-to-check-if-a-value-is-not-in-an-array-using-jquery))

Any ideas why it still continues to say `Please continue Kindly`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all the value of `instance_name` will not be updated on blur as you are saving the value outside of the blur event.

Hence, you need to move `var instance_name = $('#instance_name').val();` inside the blur event listener. When inside the event listener you may use the shorthand `$(this).val()` to get the value.

For the condition, use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) which returns -1 if a value is not in the search array, otherwise it returns the index of the position of the value being searched (i.e 0,1,2...).

Code:

```
var not_allowed = ["test", "noah", "help", "demo"];
$("#instance_name").on("blur", function (e) {
    // $(this).val() is the value of #instance_name.
    if (not_allowed.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1) {
        $("#instance_alert").html("<font color=red>Instance exists. Please try another one.</font>");
    } else {
        $("#instance_alert").html("<font color=green>Instance does not exists. Please continue</font>");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use this:  please [$.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

```
if(jQuery.inArray("test", not_allowed) != -1) {
    console.log("is in array");
} else {
    console.log("is NOT in array");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Late answer, but To check if a value **IS NOT** present in an array, you can use:

```
if(jQuery.inArray("item", the_array) === -1) {
    // item NOT in Array
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) method. The `indexOf()` method searches the array for the specified item, and returns its position. It returns -1 if the item is not found.

```
var not_allowed = ["test", "noah", "help", "demo"];    
$("#instance_name").on("blur", function (e) {
    var instance_name = $(this).val();
    if (not_allowed.indexOf(instance_name) > -1) {
        $("#instance_alert").html("<font color=red>Instance exists. Please try another one.</font>");
    } else {
        $("#instance_alert").html("<font color=green>Instance does not exists. Please continue</font>");
    }
});
```